# CSS rotation text aliassed in FF and Chrome

Tags: css, rotation

Does anyone know why the extra translatez(1px) option in the transform causes the text to be anti aliased?

I have some div with text in it:

```
<div class="rotated">This is a piece of rotated text</div>
```

and some CSS to rotate it (simplified):

```
.rotated { transform: rotate(4deg); }
```

When I run this in the browser it looks crappy.. but if I add another translate to the CSS the output is fine:

```
.rotated { transform: rotate(4deg) translateZ(1px); }
```

You can see the full snip in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/schmeitswebsolutions/k8Pge/

thx in advance